# cant send parameter with angular http.get

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to send page number and pagesize to webapi , 
but no parameter is passed , i have debugedd the app in vs code ,pagingModel has pageSize and PageNumber as member and they both have value, but when I open chrome dev tool there is no paramethere in request url
is there something wrong with my code ?

```
getTasks(pagingModel: IPagingModel): Promise<TaskList> {
    const url = this.taskUrl;
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    let option: RequestOptions;
     // tslint:disable-next-line:forin
     for (const key in pagingModel) {
      params.set(key, pagingModel[key]);
     }

    option = new RequestOptions( {search: params, params: params});

    return this.http.get(url, option)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json() as TaskList)
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: `search: params, params: params` - Calling both a parameter name and its variable `params` is a risky road to take.

Comment: just trying to pass it with all available option in get ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code was fine, I had just to import URLSearchParams

```
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

I was not importing it before, and I don't know why but v code gave me no error .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is the best way. But also by this way, working.

```
const url = this.taskUrl;
url += '?';

Object.keys(pagingModel).forEach(key => {
        url += `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(pagingModel[key])}&`;
    });

return this.http.get(url)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json() as TaskList)
           .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

Comment: this works, but I am not sure if this is the best way.

Comment: @Arash your code is working for me. I just not passed `params` key, passed only `search` key. Seems `params` key is not a valid argument.`new RequestOptions({ search: params });`. And also can't understand why it is not working for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this using the new `HttpClientModule` in Angular v4

```
import {HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";
const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('pagenumber', '<your para>')
    .set('pagesize', "<your para>");

this.http
    .get("<requrl>", {params}) // mind this you dont have to use res.json() as httpClientModule has .json() by default
```

> we are building the HTTPParams object by chaining set()
>   methods.because HTTPParams is immutable, and its API methods
>   do not cause object mutation. Instead, a call to set will return a new
>   HttpParams object containing the new value properties.

The following wont work

```
params.set('pagenumber', '<para>')
params.set('pagesize', "<para>");
```

Comment: @angular/common/http"; has no exported member HttpParams

Comment: @Arash you have to use the http client module instead of http module, add the import to `HttpClientModule` in imports array of `Ngmodule`

Comment: same error , 
@angular/common/htt has no exported memebr  HttpClientModule

Comment: you are using angular v4 or v2 ?

Comment: @angular/cli: 1.2.6
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.4
@angular/common: 4.3.4
@angular/compiler: 4.3.4
@angular/core: 4.3.4
@angular/forms: 4.3.4
@angular/http: 4.3.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.4
@angular/router: 4.3.4
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.4
@angular/language-service: 4.3.4

Comment: did you add this line `import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";` to ngmodule and also the `HttpClientModule` to the imports array ? check this [link](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/FootBallScores/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts)